# Multiple ints to const char*

Tags: string, date, char, int, constants

I'm trying to make as string out of multiple ints.

Let's say:

```
int year = 1995;
int month = 12;
int day = 18;
const char* date = ("%d-%d-%d", month, day, year);
```

I get:

```
error: invalid conversion from 'int' to 'const char*' [-fpermissive]
```

What's the best way to go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, convert your parameters to strings with `std::to_string()`.

```
string m = std::to_string(month);
string d = std::to_string(day);
string y = std::to_string(year);
```

Then, concatenate them:

```
string datestr = m + d + y;
```

Finally, convert that string into a `char const*`, using `c_str()`, which converts a string int to a C-like string.

```
char const* date = date.c_str();
```